# Creating new polygons from multiple points with centroid coordinates of polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, centroids

How to Create from an Excel file or shapefile with multiple points with the coordinates of the centroids polygons, now I would like to create an amount x of polygons with the information of the points, it is possible to create an amount x of records for a polygon.

I have a layer of polygons of urban areas and I want to add the information of the points in a new layer of these polygons, or to replicate the polygon by each centroid point as seen in the image.

[image]

Comment: Add a sample of the excel file

Comment: Hi, I just added an image where you see the selection of a cantindad x of records but I want to create the same amount x of polygons as seen in the image

Comment: Are you wanting to create multiple polygons for each point feature?  Or you have multiple stacked point features and you want to create a polygon for each feature?  How big do you want your polygons to be?

Comment: Hello Midavalo, it would be the second option but the already I have a basic layer of polygons would duplicate or replicate the information of the points in several new polygons.

Comment: And please have some patience with me, my english is not very good and I apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: @ricardo I voted for reopening, but I deleted the _or other gis software?_ part in the question title because you should ask a question for a specific GIS software. However, you may write a similar _new_ question and ask for solutions with any other software.